# Is there a word for the fear that one might be a hypochondriac?

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

This seems like a fundamental thing that would have a word for it—oftentimes one worries about a health condition, but then one is afraid to get it looked into as one is afraid of being a hypochondriac.

Comment: I don't believe such a word exists. I suppose it could be named hypocondriaphobia, or hypocondriaception. :P

Comment: Being afraid of being viewed as a hypochondriac doesn't seem that "fundamental" or common to me... But here are some phrases that come to mind. You fear being viewed as *making a mountain out of a molehill* or *worrying about nothing.*

Comment: **Agoraphobia** or **phobophobia**. Being afraid of being afraid, did you mean? Wow!

Comment: Agoraphobia relates to public places, and phobophobia is unfortunately too broad.

Comment: If we accept that "hypochondria" is a both a "medical condition" in and of itself, ***and*** "excessive fear of having a medical condition" then arguably fear of being (diagnosed as) a hypochondriac is just a form of hypochondria anyway, so it doesn't really need a special extra word (or maybe we should call it ***recursive hypochondria***).

Comment: wow, I really like _recursive hypochondria_ :-)

Comment: Afraid of *being* a hypochondriac, or afraid of being *seen* as one?

Comment: Afraid of being one, though I suppose both could use words.